# How can I subset in order?

Tags: r, subset

I created Beta Distribution B(1,3) with 500,000 random samples by `by <- rbeta(500000, 1, 3)`, then I calculate `sum(log(1-by))` but I want to calculate in group of 5 of `by` that mean I take first 5 samples of `by` and calculate `sum(log(1-by))` of that first 5 samples, after that take the next 5 sample (5th to 10th samples) and calculte `sum(log(1-by))`, doing that till the end. Could you help me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate should do the job

```
aggregate(by ~ rep(1:100000, each = 5), FUN = function(x) sum(log(1-x)))
```

This does `log(1-by)` for each element of `by` then sums those for 1st to 5th, 6th to 10th etc. as seen here

```
> V1 <- rbeta(6, 1, 3)
> log(1-V1)
[1] -1.03779783 -0.04631726 -0.02731994 -0.99583209 -0.03959935 -0.02131620
> aggregate(V1 ~ rep(1:2, each = 3), FUN = function(x) sum(log(1-x)))
  rep(1:2, each = 3)        V1
1                  1 -1.111435
2                  2 -1.056748
```

To extract that column of summed values as a vector just add `[,2]` after to make `aggregate(...)[,2]`.

Comment: I have a doubt, could you help me resolve?. For example, I create a vector `V <- rbeta(20, 1,2)` and group it into 2 group of 10 (each group 10 samples) `V ~ rep(1:2, each=10)` and calculate function `sum(log(1-V)) / sum(log(1-V))` with numerator is samples from 6th to 10th position and denominator from 1st to 5th position?

Comment: `aggregate(...)[1,2] / aggregate(...)[2,2]`